# Tomcat jdbc connection pool - Pool-Cleaner Memory Leak

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, memory-leaks

I have scoured the internet for over a day and still cannot seem to find a working solution.  I am using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.35 and Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool with Tomcat 6.0.32 and I am not able to start/stop/reload an existing Web Application without the tomcat jdbc cleaner pool thread not being able to be stopped and causing memory leaks.  I have tried everything that I could find on the net about it and I still have the same issues.  If I stop the container, it wouldn't matter since once the container stops, the threads are dead.  BUT, since I am not stopping the container, just merely stopping the application, BAM! - Memory Leak.

This is beyond frustrating and you would think that Apache would have a detailed solution for this, but they don't.

Anyone know how to resolve this once and for all?

Oh, and yes - I de-register the drivers and run AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown() in a ServletContextListener and have tried both to deploy the drivers in $CATALINA_HOME/lib and WEB-INF/lib, but still have the same problem.

**Update:**

It looks like the connection pool may NOT be the issue.  If I use DBCP, I do not get errors about memory leaks, but if I run "Find Leaks" on the manager page, Tomcat definitely discovers a leak in the application - just from starting it, running an operation that reads from the database, then stopping it.  If I just start/stop it, then no issue reported.  I have made sure that all connections/statements/resultSets are properly closed.  If I switch back to Tomcat JDBC, I still have the same issue, it just gets reported (at least as far as I can tell) during stop/restart of the application as [Pool-Cleaner] Thread not being able to be stopped, and the Manager finding leaks when clicking the "Find Leaks" button.

Comment: Use connection pool HikariCP

Answer (score 2):

Your JDBC drivers should be in $CATALINA_HOME/lib, and your database connection pools should be configured in the server.xml file using `<Resource>` tags. You *context*.xml file for the webapp should then link to the global data source with a `<ResourceLink>` tag.

This way connections are global and shared by all webapps connecting to the same database. Connections will not be released when a webapp is stopped or restarted, because they don't belong to the webapp, they belong to Tomcat.

No database connection memory leak, assuming all your webapp servlets/handlers clean up their resources correctly in finally blocks.

*FYI:* Deregistring a driver doesn't release any resources, such as open Connections, Statements, and ResultSets. It just prevents new connections from being created.

Comment: I just did this and still have the same issue - Memory Leak in Tomcat Manager and This error still showing when I stop/start/reload the application:

`Sep 22, 2015 9:30:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test] appears to have started a thread named [[Pool-Cleaner]:Tomcat Connection Pool[1-4814818]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.`

Comment: Sounds like *your* webapp is starting that thread, not Tomcat.

Comment: Since I never explicitly start this thread, how is it getting started?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, discovered that this is NOT AT ALL related to JDBC (face-palm).  Turns out this is an RMI issue, so I am now going to re-post this question as a new question.

Thanks everyone for your time.